# PHP: Resize image

Tags: php, image, resize

I saw this script on a site, and tried to get it working with my code.
But when i upload the image i get nothing echo'ed out, and my image is not resized.
I hope someone could see what im doing wrong.

**class.imageResizer.php**

```
<?php
class ImgResizer {
var $originalFile = '$newName';
function ImgResizer($originalFile = '$newName') {
    $this -> originalFile = $originalFile;
}
function resize($newWidth, $targetFile) {
    if (empty($newWidth) || empty($targetFile)) {
        return false;
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($this -> originalFile);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($this -> originalFile);
    $newHeight = ($height / $width) * $newWidth;
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
        unlink($targetFile);
    }
    imagejpeg($tmp, $targetFile, 95);
}
}
?>
```

**The uploader**

```
//If no errors do this
if (isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors)
{
    //Resizing the picture
    include 'class.imageResizer.php';

    $work = new ImgResizer('users/$username/$imageName');
    $work -> resize(400, 'users/$username/$username-246.$extension');

    $sql = "UPDATE members SET user_pic='http://www.something.net/$newName' WHERE username='$username'";
    $_SESSION['user_pic'] = $newName;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close($conn);
}
```

The $newName = users/theusername/theusername.theextension

The $imageName = theusername.theextension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from having file permission issues, one of the issues here is the single quotes. 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Instead of this,

```
$work = new ImgResizer('users/$username/$imageName');
$work -> resize(400, 'users/$username/$username-246.$extension');
```

Change it to

```
$work = new ImgResizer("users/$username/$imageName");
$work -> resize(400, "users/$username/$username-246.$extension");
```

Or to make it more predictable / readable

```
$work = new ImgResizer("users/".$username."/".$imageName);
$work -> resize(400, "users/".$username."/".$username."-246.".$extension);
```

Same goes for this line,

```
var $originalFile = '$newName';
function ImgResizer($originalFile = '$newName') {
```

Either drop the single quotes, or change it to double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing you are placing variables in single quotes where you should be using double quotes. The variables are read as text rather than values:

Wrong:

```
$work = new ImgResizer('users/$username/$imageName');
```

Right:

```
$work = new ImgResizer("users/$username/$imageName");
```

Comment: Ahh, so there's my problem. Thx!